# why? pySerial write valve and readline() value are same

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

Serial communication readline data can't get right data. the readline data is prior write data returning but sometime can get different data.

```
    import time
    import serial
    
    ser = serial.Serial()
    rereport = "COM16"   
    ser.baudrate = 9600
    ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS #number of bits per bytes
    ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE #set parity check: no parity
    ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE #number of stop bits
    ser.timeout = 1
    
    ser.xonxoff = True  #disable software flow control
    ser.rtscts = 0  #disable hardware (RTS/CTS) flow control
    ser.dsrdtr = 0  #disable hardware (DSR/DTR) flow control
    
    ser.open()
    
    ser.flushInput() #flush input buffer, discarding all its contents
    ser.flushOutput()#flush output buffer, aborting current output 
                
    ser.reset_input_buffer()
    ser.reset_output_buffer()
    
    wdata = "#001STA"
    ser.write(wdata.encode())
    
    time.sleep(1)
    
    print("Start")
    
    if ser.is_open:
        myBytes = ser.readline()
        if myBytes:
            while 1:
                ser.write(wdata.encode())
                time.sleep(0.1)
                myBytes = ser.readline().decode()
                print(myBytes)
                time.sleep(1)
        else:
            print("Can not connect")
```

---

I expected
#001,▒▒▒,25080,009,009,004,004,000,66,00700,069,042,0000000000000000000000000

But

```
    #001STA <- write
    #001STA <- readline
    #001STA <- write
    #001STA <- readline
```

#Another code but same result

```
    import keyboard
    import serial, time
    
    
    ser = serial.Serial()
    ser.port = "COM16"
    
    ser.baudrate = 9600
    ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS #number of bits per bytes
    ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE #set parity check: no parity
    ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE #number of stop bits
    ser.timeout = 1
    ser.writeTimeout = 0.5  
    
    while 1:
        wrData = "001STA"
        ser.write(wrData).encode("Ascii")
        print(wrData)
        getData = ser.readline().decode("Ascii")
        print(getData)   
        time.sleep(1)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Od75u.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HSDj.png)

Comment: `ser.xonxoff = True  #disable software flow control` -- Code does not match comment! BUG?

Comment: "*the readline data is prior write data returning*" -- Your analysis doesn't make any sense. It looks more like stale read data. What happens when you try increasing the timeout and/or clearing your buffer prior to a new readline?

Comment: I changed title because the title may confuse your understanding.

Comment: I tried many different code but same result which write and readline vale are same.
example.
wrData = ser.write("001STA").encode("Ascii")
print(wrData)
while 1:
    ser.write(wrData.encode("Ascii"))
    getData = ser.readline().decode("Ascii")
    print(getData)   

result
001STA
001STA